# Using dplyr to mutate() contract duration, payment counts, and total payout

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series, dplyr

A simplified structure of my data is as follows:

```
>ID <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B")
>Date = seq(as.Date("2000/07/01"), as.Date("2000/07/10"), "days")
>Amt <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)

>E <- data.frame(Date = Date, ID = ID, Amt = Amt)
>E
         Date ID  Amt
1  2000-07-01  A  5.9
2  2000-07-02  B  8.2
3  2000-07-03  B  5.2
4  2000-07-04  C 16.0
5  2000-07-05  A  9.6
6  2000-07-06  B  7.8
7  2000-07-07  C  9.3
8  2000-07-08  C  9.8
9  2000-07-09  A 10.0
10 2000-07-10  B 12.0
```

The structure of the *actual* data, which covers 14,460 payments on 1864 contracts at 1830 locations over 15 years (an irregularly-spaced, daily series) :

```
> str(exp)
'data.frame':   14460 obs. of  14 variables (not all shown):
 $ ID            : Factor w/ 1864 levels "C10677","C10717"... 
 $ Loc           : Factor w/ 1830 levels "(BLANK CREEK BRIDGE)" ...
 $ Year          : int  2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 ...
 $ Month         : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Day           : int  5 6 6 7 11 11 12 16 16 16 ...
 $ MonthCount    : int  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
 $ MonthTotal    : num  10140428 10140428 10140428 10140428 10140428 ...
 $ Date          : Date, format: "2000-07-05" "2000-07-06" "2000-07-06"...
```

My goal is the automation of the data ingestion task for the purposes of building a budget forecast that will live in a ShinyR application (far in the future). I used a SQL query to build the `$MonthCount` variable before I was better acquainted with the dplyr library (thanks to DataCamp), and now would like to know:

**What is the most efficient way to use the dplyr library to (mutate?) the following features:**

1) *"Contract Length"*: takes the difference between the `Date` of the last and first payments on a given contract `ID` and returns a `numeric` type.

2) *"Contract Payment Count"*: counts how many payments were made on a given contract `ID` (presumably over the `Contract Length`). Assuming non-zero payments, this should = the count of how many times an `ID` appears in that column.

3) *"Contract Payment Total"*: sums the `Amt` of each payment made to a given `ID`, (again, presumably over the realization I'm calling `Contract Length`).

Am I correct in thinking a single `mutate()` call would be able to handle the creation of all three of these features?

EDIT:

Having just picked up dplyr, I am chipping away at #1 with `E1 <- mutate(E, ContractLength = max(Date) - min(Date))` but this returns a column of '9 days' since I'm not properly identifying a 'for each ID' clause...

Comment: Did you make any attempt on your own with dplyr?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, but I haven't gotten far because I'm unsure of the logic I should be using within the mutate function.  I'm at `E1 <- mutate(E, ContractLength = max(Date) - min(Date))` but don't know how to tell it "for each contract"... [edit: the code I gave properly returns a colum of '9 days']

Comment: What is your specific programming question? Please show us [the code you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and why it didn't meet your needs. Sharing your attempts helps everyone. It demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer.

Comment: @Henrik I have added the current state of my attempts at #1, but as I said I am going through the dplyr tutorial on DataCamp and haven't been introduced to the logic necessary to calculate a date length 'for each' contract...

Comment: To start with, please have a look at the [`dplyr` vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should provide what you want.

```
E %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(contract_len = as.numeric(difftime(last(Date), first(Date), unit="days")),
         num_payments = n(),
         payment = sum(Amt))

  ID contract_len num_payments  payment
1  A            8            3 26.64588
2  B            8            4 47.79380
3  C            4            3 27.79909
```

Comment: Thank you, and apologies to anyone reading this for the simplicity of my query.  In fact, my next section on DataCamp is on the pipe operator (I'm getting there!)

Comment: yep, that's what I got : `E %>%
  group_by (ID) %>%
  summarise(
         min_dt = min(Date),
         max_dt = max(Date),
         CPC = max_dt - min_dt,
         CPT = sum(Amt))`

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started with #1 and #2 - I think what you're struggling with is that first you need to summarize, then you need to mutate?

```
contract_stats <- E %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(
    min_date=min(Date),
    max_date=max(Date),
    contract_count=n()
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    length = max_date - min_date  
  )

contract_stats
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

  ID   min_date   max_date contract_count length
1  A 2000-07-01 2000-07-09              3 8 days
2  B 2000-07-02 2000-07-10              4 8 days
3  C 2000-07-04 2000-07-08              3 4 days
```